# Replacing light fixture UK unable to determine which wire is which

Tags: wiring, lighting, light-fixture, neutral, uk

We had our kitchen redone within the last year, part of that was adding a new light fitting which was to be replaced later in the year.

That time is now, I've just taken the old one off which has seemingly the same connections, but after plugging into what I thought was the exact same position, our power just keeps tripping.

I have been putting the Blue and Brown the the Neutral on the fitting, the middle in the Earth, and the Black and Red in the Live.

Could anyone suggest what  I am doing wrong?

Stupidly, I didn't take a photo of the light fitting before I removed it so I'm not sure if the combination has been mixed up.

Thanks.

[image][image]

Comment: Can you provide a photo of the wiring at the switch that controls this fixture?

Comment: Given that red and brown are live, and blue and black are neutral.  You seem to have been just short-circuiting your mains feed.

Comment: think about it, binding  together wires in the same cable makes no sense.  That would make them redundant, and the cable could do with fewer wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of those cables goes to a switch loop. You need to find out which. Open up the switch that controls this light and see what wire colours it has.

If the brown and blue (new colours) are the switch then connect

- red to brown (which takes live to the switch)
- blue to the "L" terminal of the the light - blue is switched live so you must  put red tape around the blue wire.
- black to the "N" terminal of the light (neutral)
- put a green/yellow sleeve over the bare earth wires and connect them using an approved connector. If the lamp has metal parts, they need to be connected to these earths too. The middle terminal in your second photo would probably be intended for this. Check for continuity between all metal parts and the earth wires.

---

UK Wiring colours

```
              Old       New
 Live         Red       Brown
 Neutral      Black     Blue
```